# How many connected components could the intersection of $\{A \in M_n(\mathbb R): \rho(A) < 1\}$ and an affine subspace in $M_n(\mathbb R)$ have?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, path-connected

Let $\mathcal E = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb R): \rho(A) < 1\}$ where $\rho(\cdot)$ is the spectral radius and $\mathcal U$ be an affine space in $M_n(\mathbb R)$. If we assume $\mathcal E \cap \mathcal U \neq \emptyset$, how many connected components could the intersection have?

In proving $\mathcal E$ is connected, I know we can use a path $(1-t)A + t 0$ but if $B$ is in the intersection, $(1-t)B$ could not be guaranteed in the intersection.

Comment: Intersections of convex sets are convex

Comment: $\mathcal E$ is not convex.

Comment: Just as a curious observer could you provide an example of two matrices whose path leaves $\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: @user25959 You can take $\pmatrix{a & 10\\  0 & a}$ and $\pmatrix{b & 0 \\10 & b}$. Make suitable choices of $a, b$.

Comment: @user25959 he is right, and $a=b=0$ already suffice to show it. I got confused with the spectral radius vs. operator norm

Comment: I see that - I had thought that spectral radius behaves somewhat like a norm but this example shows one way it's not quite alike

Comment: Maybe you could use a similar argument as for proving $\mathcal E$ is connected but using, for $A$ in the affine subspace $\mathcal S$, $(1-t)A+t 0_{\mathcal S}$ where $0_{\mathcal S}$ is the orthogonal projection of $0$ onto $\mathcal S$. First I think that if $0_{\mathcal S}\notin \mathcal E$, then the intersection is empty (I have no proof so far) and maybe it will give more intuition, maybe something like $\rho(0_{\mathcal S}) = \inf_{A\in\mathcal S} \rho(A)$ is true. All this is only intuition and may be quite wrong or useless.

Comment: @P.Quinton as $\mathcal E$ is not convex there will be affine one-dimensional spaces where the intersection will be disconnected. You cannot hope to show that it is connected. By modifying the example in the comment above one should be able to always find a line whose intersection with $\mathcal E$ has $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ components.

Comment: @s.harp: Could you elaborate your idea to a full answer so I will accept it? Thanks.

Comment: @user9527 I did so, but this does not answer your question, it only provides you with a lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration on a comment, it provides only a lower bound on the amount of components you can get and I only look at a one-dimensional affine subspace (also known as a line).

The first step is to look at the matrix
$$A(t;a):=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\,t\\a\,(1-t)& 0\end{pmatrix},$$
which has spectral radius $|a|\sqrt{|t-t^2|}$. The values of $t$ for which the spectral radius is $≤1$ are
$$\mathcal D(a):=[B_1(a), B_2(a)]\,\cup\,[B_3(a),B_4(a)].$$
(To be concrete, $B_1(a)=\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2a}$, $B_2(a)= \frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2a}$, $B_3(a) = \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2a}$, $B_4(a)=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2a}$, but these values don't matter.) What matters is that you have two intervals where the gap between them becomes arbitrarily small as $a\to2$. Further the length of the intervals does not grow unboundedly as $a\to2$.

Now look at the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} A(c_1 t-d_1; a_1) & 0 \\ 0 & A(c_2 t-d_2; a_2)\end{pmatrix}.$$
The values for $t$ where this matrix has spectral radius $≤1$ is
$$(c_1\cdot\mathcal D(a_1)+d_1)\cap (c_2\cdot \mathcal D(a_2)+d_2).$$

Manipulating $a_1,c_1,d_1$ you have basically arbitrary freedom to tune the following things on $c_1\cdot\mathcal D(a_1)+d_1$:

1. The gap between the two intervals can be made arbitrarily small (tune parameter $a$).
2. The gap can be shifted to wherever you want (tune parameter $d$).
3. The length of the intervals can be made as large as you like.

Note that adjusting the length of the intervals alters the length of the gap and the position of the gap. Clearly you can correct the position again, but it is also important to note that you can correct the length of the gap (by making it smaller), since this procedure will not shorten the intervals beyond a certain factor.

All this was just to give a sound background to the pictorial story I'm going to tell.

---

Here is an abstraction of what you can let the two domains from before look like:
[image: two domains]

The intersection of these two looks like:

[image: intersection of two domains]

You see $3$ components. Now if you are looking at $M_{2n}(\Bbb R)$ you can take a look at the line
$$\begin{pmatrix} A(c_1 t-d_1;a_1) &... &0\\ 0 &\ddots &\vdots \\ 0& ... &A(c_nt -d_n;a_n) \end{pmatrix}$$
and the intersection of this line with $\mathcal E$ will by the intersection of $n$ domains with the given parameters. An example of what you can tune for $M_8(\Bbb R)$ (ie $4$ domains) is the following picture:

[image: four domains and their intersection]

This story is a lower bound of $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ on the amount of components achievable with a line.